# Sync data between different SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization

I have two database with same tables name and column name. However its name is different and it have been installed in different SQL Server version.

One is SQL Server 2008 R2 and the other is SQL Server 2012. Is there any way to sync data between them?

Should I use replication, or any tools? I don't mind if it need paying to buy tool.

Comment: backup the one version and restore the backup to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

1. SQL Server Import/Export Wizard : It is better to use it if we are not doing any manipulation with the data.
2. SSIS package which can be used if amount of data is large and you want to schedule it for running and do data manipulation before loading the data.

Comment: What if it has installed in two different machine

Comment: You have to create connection string for two different machine . One Connection string for source and another for destination.The user that you will be using to run the package should have access to both the servers.